# Conversion from void* to the pointer of the base class

Tags: c++, casting

I have some hierarchy: base, derived classes and some structure storing user data as void*. That void can store both Base and Derived classes pointers. Main problem that I do not know what is stored there base or derived pointer.

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
  int type;
};
class Derived: public Base
{};

Base* base;//init base pointer
Derived* derived;//init derived pointer
void* base_v = base;
void* derived_v = derived;
//void pointers are correct. They point to base and derived variables.

//try to get type field after converting pointers back
Derived* d_restored = (Derived*)derived_v;//d_restored correct
Base* b_restored = (Base*)base_v;//b_restored correct
Base* d_restored_to_base = (Base*)derived_v;// INCORRECT
```

How to convert void* to get [type] field for both pointers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using multiple inheritance?

Comment: i don't know why you are trying that conversion in an object oriented language..anyway you should use dynamic_cast instead

Comment: yes. Derived class in original is derived from 4 classes. and base has parent too.

Comment: TGadfly: Then you need dynamic_cast

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`void*`'s can only be converted back to their original type. When you store a `Derived*` in a `void*`, you can only cast back to `Derived*`, **not** `Base*`.

This is especially noticeable with multiple inheritance, as your derived object might not necessarily be at the same address as your base. If you really need to store things (and retrieve things) with `void*`, *always* cast to the base type first, so you have a stable way of getting the object back:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base { int type; };
struct intruder { int iminyourclassstealingyourbase; };
struct derived : intruder, base {};

int main()
{
    derived d; d.type = 5;

    void* good = (base*)&d;
    void* bad = &d;

    base* b1 = (base*)good;
    base* b2 = (base*)bad;

    std::cout << "good: " << b1->type << "\n";
    std::cout << "bad: " << b2->type << "\n";
}
```

If you then want to go back to the derived type, use a `dynamic_cast` (or `static_cast` if you're guaranteed it has to be of the derived type.)

Comment: Thank you. that was GREAAAAAAT answer. It solved my problem and explained ->void* and void*-> conversions. It is a great idea to store in void* not derived but pre-converted to base pointer.

Answer (score 4):

When you use multiple inheritance, the resulting object is internally acting much like a composite, conceptually something like this:

```
struct Derived {
  Base1 b1;
  Base2 b2;
};
```

You will get different addresses for your instance of Derived depending on whether you cast it to Base1 or Base2. So, you can't reliably do what you want to do. You'll need to keep a pointer to one of the involved types, and use `dynamic_cast`

Alternatively, you could make your own rules - saying that you always store the address of your instance casted to a specific base class, and always cast back to this base class. This is very error-prone, and I'd strongly recommend that you try to store a pointer to a common base class if at all possible.

Comment: If he keeps a pointer to one of the involved types, then can't he just do `static_cast<Derived*>(b1)`? (assuming he keeps a pointer to `Base1*`). The `static_cast` will do pointer offset adjustments as necessary. In other words, what does the `dynamic_cast` buys you over `static_cast`?

Comment: The ability to cast between bases.

Answer (score 1):

If you know it's a derived pointer and you want to get a base pointer, you can do this:

```
Base* d_restored_to_base = (Base*)(Derived*)derived_v;
```

You will find that the Base* points to a different location than the Derived*, so the intermediary cast is required.

Comment: I tried it works, but I do not know what pointer to what type is stored

Answer (score -2):

Use `dynamic_cast`, it can dynamically tell you if the pointer points to a `Base` object or not.

Comment: Not coming from a void* it can't.