# Calling pure virtual function on Box2D GetUserData's result

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, box2d, game-physics

First of all, I use Cocos2d-x-2.1.5 and Box2D 2.3.0 (not pretty sure how to check which exactly, but found that info on cocos' repository).

My problem appears when I try to call the pure virtual function from the object which was assigned to the b2Body object via SetUserData method.

I scheduled a method updateBodies to update sprites which are the part of my game object's representation.

```
void GameplayLogicLayer::updateBodies(float pDeltaTime)
{
    mWorld->Step(pDeltaTime, 10, 10);

    for(b2Body* tBodies = mWorld->GetBodyList(); tBodies; tBodies = tBodies->GetNext()){
        A* tA = (static_cast<A*>(tBodies->GetUserData()));
        if(tA != NULL)
        {
            tA->callPureVirtualFunction();
            tA->callFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

The program crashes when it tries to execute callPureVirtualMethodFunction().

My hierarchy of objects is below (A contains mBody, which is b2Body type; B and C extends A):
[image: Hierarchy]

In the constructors of B and C I create Box2D body and link the object to the b2Body by:

```
mBody = pWorld.CreateBody(&tBodyDef);
mBody->SetUserData(this);
```

Do you have an idea how it crashes while executing pure virtual function, but works well when I call methods from the base class?

EDIT - in response to LearnCocos2d user.

Here is the A class content.

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "Box2D/Box2D.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void callPureVirtualFunction() = 0;
    void callFunction();
protected:
    CCSprite* mSprite;
    b2Body* mBody;
    b2Fixture* mFixture;
};

#endif // __A_H__
```

And C class implementation.
.h file:

```
#ifndef __C_H__
#define __C_H__

#include "A.h"

class C : public A
{
public:
    C(CCLayer& pParent, b2World& pWorld, const char* pFileName, float pPositionX, float pPositionY, float pWidth, float pHeight);
    C();

    virtual void callPureVirtualFunction();
private:
    bool mWithSensor;
};

#endif // __C_H__
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "C.h"
#include "../Utilities/Constants.h"

C::C(CCLayer& pParent, b2World& pWorld, const char* pFileName, float pPositionX, float pPositionY, float pWidth, float pHeight)
{
    mWithSensor = false;

    // GRAPHICS
    if(pFileName)
    {
        mSprite = CCSprite::create(pFileName);
        mSprite->setPosition(CCPointMake(pPositionX, pPositionY));
        pParent.addChild(mSprite);
    }

    b2BodyDef tBodyDef;
    tBodyDef.type = b2_kinematicBody;
    tBodyDef.position.Set( pPositionX / PIXELS_IN_METER, pPositionY / PIXELS_IN_METER );
//  tCollisionBoxBodyDef.userData = this;
    tBodyDef.userData = NULL;

    mBody = pWorld.CreateBody(&tBodyDef);
    mBody->SetGravityScale(0.f);
    mBody->SetUserData(this);

    b2PolygonShape tBodyShape;
    tBodyShape.SetAsBox(pWidth / 2.f / PIXELS_IN_METER, pHeight / 2.f / PIXELS_IN_METER);

    b2FixtureDef tBodyFixtureDef;
    tBodyFixtureDef.shape = &tBodyShape;
    tBodyFixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
    tBodyFixtureDef.density = 10.0f;
    tBodyFixtureDef.restitution = 0.1f;

    mFixture = mBody->CreateFixture( &tBodyFixtureDef );
}

C::C()
{

}

/*virtual*/ void C::callPureVirtualFunction()
{  

}
```

Comment: And what is return type of tBodies->GetUserData()?

Comment: `CCLog("Type name 1: %s.", typeid(tBodies->GetUserData()).name());
CCLog("Type name 2: %s.", typeid(tA).name());`

Executing these two lines just below checking if tA equals null returns:
`Type name 1: Pv.
Type name 2: P1A.` But in general GetUserData returns `void*`.

Comment: how is pureVirtualFunction implemented? Maybe it isn't and remained pure virtual (ie no actual implementation)?

Comment: Only two classes inherits from class A and they both implements the method. I even tried to make debugging easier and created the `callPureVirtualFunction` method, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445105/conversion-from-void-to-the-pointer-of-the-base-class -- does that solve your problem? You cannot convert C* -> void* -> A*, for example. You can only do C*->A*->void*->A* and only on platforms where code and data pointers are the same size.

Comment: Also, you do realize that your pointer to tBodyDef you pass to CreateBody becomes invalid after that C::C constructor is done?

Comment: Yes, I realize.
The linked content doesn't solve the problem. I changed SetUserData call to: `mBody->SetUserData(dynamic_cast<A*>(this));`